# I get a high cutoff frequency value

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, ltspice

[image]When I read the Bode diagram at 0 dB I get 678.8KHz of cutoff frequency and when I change the settings of the frequency and voltage inputs I get the same Bode diagram and the same cutoff frequency. the cutoff frequency that I found is very high I don't know where the problem is normally must be small

I don't know what the problem is can you help me?[image]

Comment: Check your wire connections between the transistors and `C1A, C1B`: in your schematic the wire ust goes above those nets.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen what do you mean ?

Comment: The horizontal wire that goes from themidpoint of `C1A, C1B` and is supposed to tie up the midpoints of the transitors and ground them, is not the same as in the reference schematic.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thank you for your help, I edited the post but the problem remains the same.

Comment: When you say that you "change the settings of frequency", are you referring to changing `V1`'s value from (say) 10 Hz to 20 Hz, or similar? What exactly are you doing? Please be specific.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen it is electroencephalogram circuit i need to draw from 1 to 3 and i need to do the simulation as output. I have a lot of waves and each wave has different frequencies so each time I have to enter a frequency value and look at the bode diagram result that's what I want to do but each time I get the same cutoff frequency and a very high value which is false
for example if I had 10Hz I change and I do 20 Hz to watch is there a change and the same for the voltage

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

I think I see what the problem is now. You are using an `.AC` analysis, but you are changing a specific frequency, which means you're interested in a `.TRAN` analysis. Or maybe you don't know how to use the cursors.

Just so you know, `.AC` means frequency analysis, and that uses a different stimulus, whose value is denoted `AC 1` inside your `V1`. It also has `SINE(0 100u 10)`, but that stimulus applies to `.TRAN`, or a time domain analysis.

The difference between the two is that in `.AC`, the stimulus accounts for a sum of all the possible frequencies, as if the source is the Fourier transform of a Dirac impulse. Then, the response of the circuit will show a frequency magnitude and phase of all the possible frequencies that it can give.

In `.TRAN` the voltage source can only supply one sine (with the `SINE()` source), but that will show the time variation of that wave, including transients.

At this point, I'm still a bit confused as to what *exactly* you want to see, but here are two versions:

- If you want an `.AC` analysis then the response of the output at a certain frequency means either using the cursors (<kbd>R-Click</kbd> on the trace's label in the waveform viewer) and then use <kbd>L-Click</kbd> to move them, while reading the values, or use `.meas` scripts to measure the values.
- If you want a `.TRAN` analysis then you need to change the simulation card, `.ac dec 1000 1 1000000`, to be `.tran 1` (for a 1 second timespan), or `.tran 10` (for a 10 s timespan), or whatever goal you have in mind. Then you can, again, use either the cursors, or the `.meas`, or the FFT, to perform measuring.

BTW, it's much easier and far less reading-error-prone to use `1k` and `1meg` -- note: `meg` is used for `1e6` and `m` for `1e-3`. You have already used those in the sources, there's nothing stopping you for using them anywhere a numeric value is needed.